# "Command not found" when trying to run a python cli application with "sudo" on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line, sudo

I have the following problem (I searched for hours but could not get it to work):
I have a python cli application (coded by myself). I created a fresh conda environment (with python 3.9.1) and installed `myapp` locally via `pip install .` into the env. All went well and I could successfully run `myapp` from the cli without any errors.
However, part of my application needs `myapp` to be called with `sudo`. By doing so, I received the error: `Command not found: myapp`.

My question is now: Why is this happening (Is this, because my env is somehow not correctly activated or "linked"?)?. I read, that `sudo` uses some other paths in its `$PATH`. But how can I fix this?

Any ideas are welcome ;)
Many thanks in advance

Edit: I also tried this using `virtualenv` but same result. Furthermore, I could successfully run the same app with `sudo` on my other system, so it must has something to do with my Ubuntu (18.04) system.

Comment: When it's installed for your user, it's not automatically installed for root. The same goes for `virtualenv`, which modifies environment variables that `sudo` discards. However, I'd suggest you try to run this without root privileges instead, e.g. by using a port above 1024 if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @UlrichEckhardt!
The problem is, that I call a command in this script (`lshw`) for some info on my RAM that needs root privileges. What would using a different port change here (I'm just curious)?

Comment: In that case, it wouldn't change anything.